# How to recognize Azure pipeline template expressions in bash?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, bash, shell

When I work with Azure DevOps pipeline files (yaml), I don't get any syntax highlighting in script or bash blocks:

[image: Azure DevOps pipeline with yaml syntax highlighting]

That's why I have installed [inkarkat/vim-SyntaxRange](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-SyntaxRange) and configured it to recognize bash syntax between `bash:`/`script:` and `displayName`/`condition`.

`~/.vim/after/syntax/yaml/SyntaxInclude.vim`:

```
call SyntaxRange#Include('^\ *- \(script\|bash\): |', 'condition\|displayName', 'bash')
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: Azure DevOps pipeline with SyntaxInclude plugin]

The script block looks great now, except that pipeline template variables (`${{ ... }}`) are highlighted as syntax errors.

Can I somehow overrule the syntax highlighting of `${{ ... }}`?

Comment: Not sure how inkarkat/vim-SyntaxRange works, but you can usually add new `:syntax` commands in various ways (files, autocommands, by hand, etc.)

Comment: I tried `:syntax match parens "\v\{\{.{-}\}\}"`,
`:highlight parens ctermfg=red guifg=red`, but with no effect.

Comment: It still has no effect, when I put these lines into `~/.vim/after/syntax/sh/double-braces.vim`. But these commands work after `:set syntax=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixes it:

`~/.vim/after/syntax/yaml/SyntaxInclude.vim`:

```
call SyntaxRange#Include('^\ *- \(script\|bash\): |', 'condition\|displayName', 'bash')

" Allow template variables ...

" ... in YAML
syntax match doublebraces "\v\$\{\{.{-}\}\}" containedin=ALL
highlight doublebraces ctermfg=blue guifg=blue

syntax match braces "\v\$\{[0-9A-Za-z_.]{-}\}" containedin=ALL
highlight braces ctermfg=green guifg=green

syntax match parens "\v\$\([0-9A-Za-z_.]{-}\)" containedin=ALL
highlight parens ctermfg=green guifg=green

" ... in script block
syntax match shDerefSimple "\${{.*}}" nextgroup=@shNoZSList
```

[image: Screenshot of an Azure DevOps pipeline in vim]

UPDATE: The first solution didn't not work well for some files. The updated configuration is not yet perfect but quite usable.